# No module named 'google.cloud' Dockerfile python

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a dockerfile with an `google/cloud-sdk:alpine` image. When I run it I keep getting an error saying that I am missing a module despite the fact that I installed it.

While building my image I run this

```
RUN pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

and inside my Docker container I run

```
 # pip show google-cloud
```

and I get the below output

```
Name: google-cloud
Version: 0.34.0
Summary: API Client library for Google Cloud
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-publisher@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

then I try to run a python script and get this error

```
/ # python3 ./publisher.py local create test-topic-v1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./publisher.py", line 318, in <module>
    create_topic(args.project_id, args.topic_name)
  File "./publisher.py", line 46, in create_topic
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'
```

Comment: Is it possible the image has two versions of Python, and `pip` is using one, and `python3` is the other?

Comment: Try this pip install google-cloud-pubsub

Comment: Please include your entire `Dockerfile` and the Python script you're trying to run.

Answer (score 2):

The `google-api-python-client` project is different than the `google-cloud` project, and the https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/ project is deprecated:

> WARNING: The google-cloud Python package is deprecated. On June 18, 2018, this package will no longer install any other packages. Please install the [product-specific google-cloud-* packages](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python#google-cloud-python-client) needed for your application.

You should install [`google-cloud-pubsub`](http://pypi.org/p/google-cloud-pubsub) instead.

Comment: I have tried that too and it did not solve the issue. Thank you for the respose.